# Using a Custom User the Password Validation from settings are ignored on registration

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users

In Django I created a custom User.

My issues is that the default validators are not working, any password is accepted.

I expected that the default password validators will work, because I'm inheriting the default Model/Form clases.

In Django settings I have:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 12,
        }
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
```

]

The Custom User implementation:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, MetaData, PermissionsMixin):

    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, blank=True, null=True, related_name='owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # email confirmed
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # can't login
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # staff user non super
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # superuser

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'  # username used for login
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = UserManager()

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None, is_confirmed=False, is_active=False,
                    is_staff=False, is_superuser=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an Email Address')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('User must have a Password set')
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError('User must have a First Name')
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError('User must have a Last Name')
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_confirmed = is_confirmed
        user.is_active = is_active
        user.is_staff = is_staff
        user.is_superuser = is_superuser
        user.save(using=self.db)

        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):

        user = self.create_user(email, first_name, last_name,  password=password, is_confirmed=True,
                                is_staff=True)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):

        user = self.create_user(email, first_name, last_name, password=password, is_confirmed=True,
                                is_active=True, is_staff=True, is_superuser=True)
        return user
```

and the Form:

```
class UserBaseCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """ A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordWidget(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password*'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordWidget(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Password*'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['account', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: @MohammadAli, no error just not verifying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The password is not validated because you are not calling any validator in your `UserBaseCreationForm`. You can do this in different ways and the easiest one would be just inheriting `UserCreationForm` from `django.contrib.auth.forms`.

Check the [django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L105), it calls the password validators in `_post_clean`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/), Django uses a **validate_password** method from **django.contrib.auth.password_validation.validate_password** to validate the password.

Since you are using a Custom UserCreationForm, You need to call that *validate_password* method explicitly, by implementing a form validation through password field clean method.

Simply add following code snippet in your UserBaseCreationForm class.

```
def clean_password1(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
    if password:
        try:
            password_validation.validate_password(password, self.instance)
        except ValidationError as error:
            self.add_error('password1', error)
```